# Autoopen after generate

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am newbie so please no bad comments.
I have build the code from other subject:

```
items = {'Woman','Men'}
url_test = 'http://www.Holiday.com/{}/Beach'
for i in items:
    url = url_test.format(i)
    print(url)"
```

Is there a way to auto open it after generate it?

Comment: Open it in the browser?

Comment: Well yes that is the easiest way, but i wanted to do it automatically, after it generated it, and user "TonyStark" helped me with that. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html)

```
import webbrowser
items = {'Woman','Men'}

url_test = 'http://www.Holiday.com/{}/Beach'
for i in items:
    url = url_test.format(i)
    print(url)
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```